# Проверка сайта на SQL-Инъекцию

Tags: mysql

Вот уже почти закончил свой сайт. Но не хочу допустить прошлых ошибок взлома и поэтому хотел бы уточнить, существует ли такая программа для сканера сайта на SQL-Инъекции, хочу проверить свой сайт. Дабы кто-то не хороший в него залез. Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- используйте PDO ([Почему стоит
     пользоваться PDO для работы с базой
     данных](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/));
- при обращении к БД, приводите данные к соответствующему типу.

Дополнительно, как защититься от **XSS** (думаю, пригодится):

- определиться с зоной доверия переменных;
- санитизация request-ов (`$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_COOKIE`, `$_SERVER`-переменные с пометкой `HTTP_...` - те, что приходят от клиента, к примеру, `$_SERVER('HTTP_USER_AGENT')`) - в идеале, написать свой класс-обёртку;
- использование bb-логики (bbCode) для входных данных;
- сантизация данных на выходе (опционально).

Если требуется для входных данных использовать всё-таки html-сущности(разметку), то существуют два неплохих инструмента (учитывайте их "тяжёлость"):

- [jevix](http://code.google.com/p/jevix/) (актуальной поддерживается лишь версия на perl-е) + типограф;
- [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Comment: +1, PDO раз и навсегда уничтожает инъекции.